# Docker network not using all NIC's

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My docker container is not reachable on all host network interfaces.

My host server has 2 network interfaces (and ip adresses). When running my docker container without a specific defined docker network, it works and the container is reachable on both ip adresses.

But when I'm running with a self defined docker network and add it to the docker-compose file  only 1 ip is working. The other timesout. Why does this happen?

Docker-compose file

```
    version: '3.7
services:
  servicename-1:
    #network_mode: "host"
    image: nginxdemos/hello
    init: true
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      omitted
    environment:
     ommitted
    networks:
      - a-netwerk-1
networks:
  a-netwerk-1:
    external:
      name: a-network-1
```

docker inspect network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "a-network-1",
        "Id": "df4ab5e3285c75b71f8f88f66c4c5d85ad8f2f9b17e66f960b11778007810b96",
        "Created": "2020-01-30T10:55:14.853289976+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.29.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.29.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2f2d5b2e22b3066085246ea53d1ca2c9f963b5e9138ae7202d8382be98428476": {
                "Name": "test_testservicename_1",
                "EndpointID": "c750b0d9d6ae82fec109da15d385b936f79f09bf814dd3b8d03642a2f03d46e2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1d:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.29.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```